# Add line for mean, mean + sd, and mean - sd to multiple factor scatterplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data of the form

```
cvar1  cvar1  numvar
a      x      0.1
a      y      0.2
b      x      0.15
b      y      0.25
```

That is, two categorical variables, and one numerical variable.

Using ggplot2, I can get a nice scatter plot that plots the data for each combination of `cv1` and `cv2` by doing qplot(y=numvar, x=interaction(cvar1, cvar2)). This gives me several columns of points like this:

[image]

To each of these columns I would like to add a small horizontal line representing the mean of the data points in that column. And a similar small horizontal line for the mean + sd and the mean - sd. (Kind of a bastardized box plot, but with all points visible and using mean and sd rather than median and IQR.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `abline` in `base`, e.g.

Comment: I don't see how `abline`, at least as I have used it, would help, because I have multiple columns I need to add lines to. Also, does `abline` even work with ggplot2?

Comment: gotcha. Then the `base` function you want is `segments`; I don't know what the equivalent is in `ggplot2`, hence leaving this as a comment

Comment: @BenS. There is the function `geom_abline` in `ggplot2`.  You may also want to look at `geom_vline` and `geom_hline` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a table that contains the mean and mean +/- sd for each group of points. Then you can plot lines using `geom_segment()`.

First, I create some sample data:

```
set.seed(1245)
data <- data.frame(cvar1 = rep(letters[1:2], each = 12),
                   cvar2 = rep(letters[25:26], times = 12),
                   numvar = runif(2*12))
```

This creates the table with the values that you need using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
summ <- group_by(data, cvar1, cvar2) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(numvar),
                  low = mean - sd(numvar),
                  high = mean + sd(numvar)) %>%
        gather(variable, value, mean:high)
```

The three lines do the following: First, the data is split into the groups and then for each group the three required values are calculated. Finally, the data is converted to long format, which is needed for `ggplot()`. (Maybe your are more familiar with `melt()`, which does basically the same thing as `gather()`)

And finally, this creates the plot:

```
gplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x = interaction(cvar1, cvar2), y = numvar)) +
  geom_segment(data = summ,
               aes(x = as.numeric(interaction(cvar1, cvar2)) - .5, 
                   xend = as.numeric(interaction(cvar1, cvar2)) + .5,
                   y = value, yend = value, colour = variable))
```

[image]

You probably won't want the colours. I just added them to make the example more clear.

`geom_segments()` needs the start and end coordinates of each line to be specified. Because `interaction(cvar1, cvar2)` is a factor, it needs to be converted to numeric before it is possible to do arithmetic with it. I added and subtracted 0.5 to `interaction(cvar1, cvar2)`, which makes the lines quite wide. Choosing a smaller value will make the lines shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way what does %>% signify?

Comment: You are welcome. It's a pipe operator. `x %>% f` is just another way of writing `f(x)`. It can be found in the `dpylr` and `magrittr` packages. See [here](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) for more information.